# Using ddply to apply a function across a dataframe with multiple inputs

Tags: r

Say I have:

```
df = data.frame(loc=c("The White House", "Lancaster, PA", "Durham, NC"),
     id=c(111,222,333))
```

I want to pass the location to a geocoding routine (which I have working), along with the id number, so I can append the id to the new data.

```
afun=function(x,y){
    #run geocoder - not shown cause it needs a key
    #pretend in this function I get data from the geocoder
    OP=data.frame(id=y,lat=34.4,long=-86, county="Washington")
    return(OP)
}
```

how do I use ddply to apply this function to the dataframe and return the result as a dataframe? I've tried something like:

```
ddply(df,1,afun,id=id)
```

Ideas?

Comment: Maybe alternatively you have a look into mapply().

Comment: This question is unclear. If, as you say in the comments below, your real question is more complicated, you've done a very poor job of conveying what you actually wish to do. Please revise your question.

Comment: You can always pass additional arguments to `ddply` that's why it has an ellipsis parameter

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused exactly why you are using ddply here. One solution that I see if I am understanding correctly is to use dplyr and mutate like so:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(g=x+1,h=y+3) %>%
select(g,h)
```

I feel like you must be trying to do something with a larger dataset that has a grouping variable to require ddply. Still this would also be accomplished easily with mutate and dplyr.

HTH.

Comment: Even simpler, `df %>% transmute(g=x+1,h=y+3)`

Comment: well, this is a toy function, the real function I'm try to pass is much longer and much more complicated, so I can't just use transmute

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple, use mdply:

```
mdply(select(df,x=loc,y=id),afun)
```

This takes a data.frame and spits out a data.frame.